# Mollie payment gateway for Cartthrob

Tags: cartthrob, payment-gateway

I am currently setting up a site with cartthrob, and we need the mollie gateway for payments. Is this available?

Comment: It is not available by default. But you can add it by Custom code. It is feasible in expressionengine.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't exist out of the box, but it's definitely doable via a custom gateway integration. There are more details about that here: https://www.cartthrob.com/docs/developers/payment_gateways/index.html